# How to set up Secure Auth as an IDP at Azure AD B2C. During setting up all, getting "Hardstopped by Analyze Engine" on secure auth login screen

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, idp

How to set up Secure Auth as an IDP at Azure AD B2C. During setting up all, getting "Hardstopped by Analyze Engine" on secure-auth login screen.

[image: error]

Please Some one can help here to understand why i am getting "Hardstopped by Analyze Engine" error message on screen as shown below>

Referred below link for setting up idp:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-generic-openid-connect?pivots=b2c-user-flow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-github?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

- This may occur by adaptive authentication method for blocking IP  for
  verifying user identity and authorization levels based on factors
  such as location, device status, and end user behavior. This
  authentication method delivers zero trust and improves security.

[***View Adaptive Authentication login failure scenarios*** (secureauth.com)](https://docs.secureauth.com/2104/en/view-adaptive-authentication-login-failure-scenarios.html)

- Please check if the user is present in allow/deny list  or if user
  restriction is set .It may cause the hard stop by analyze engine if
  the user/group has failure actions as in this doc.
- The call to validate the client IP using the Analyze Engine must have
  failed where IP did not pass the Analyze Engine deny list / allow
  list filter or was rejected by the IP Risk service. It also may occur
  if the Analyze Engine configuration is incompatible with WS-Trust.

**References:**

1. [Adaptive Authentication Options Explained For User/Group –
   SecureAuth Support](https://support.secureauth.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019889731-Adaptive-Authentication-Options-Explained-For-User-Group)
2. [SecureAuth compatibility guide](https://docs.secureauth.com/2104/en/secureauth-compatibility-guide.html)

You can raise a [***support request***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/support-options) regarding this scenario.